# Upload attachment asynchronously with Shrine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, shrine

I want to upload big files (over 5GB). My API works as expected, but it's synchronous.

Is there a way to upload attachments asynchronously with sidekiq? I created a worker, but since I cannot pass an object to `perform_async` method (I tried to pass `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` object, but it has been cast to string) I don't know to upload a file in this worker.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Asynchronously with Shrine only means uploading to a remote service such as S3 or MinIo (this is called "direct to S3" and requires a presign etc ..) and then your rails app can create the record, promote the file to final store and process derivatives asynchronously through Sidekiq.